# Oracle Group and Pivot - Dynamic Pivot in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like this:

```
+-----+------+------------+
| SN  | CASE | CASE_VALUE |
+-----+------+------------+
|  A  |  AA  |      1     |
|  A  |  AB  |      5     |
|  A  |  AC  |      3     |
|  A  |  AD  |      4     |
|  B  |  BA  |      5     |
|  B  |  BB  |      7     |
|  B  |  BC  |      5     |
|  B  |  BD  |      1     |
+-----+------+------------+
```

Not sure if there is any way to get

```
+-----+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+
| SN  | CASE_1 | CASE_1_VALUE | CASE_2 | CASE_2_VALUE | CASE_3 | CASE_3_VALUE | CASE_4 | CASE_4_VALUE |
+-----+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+
|  A  |   AA   |      1       |   AB   |      5       |   AC   |      3       |   AD   |      4       |
|  B  |   BA   |      5       |   BB   |      7       |   BC   |      5       |   BD   |      1       |
+-----+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------------+
```

There is no order required for those four cases

28/02/2021 Edit

If there's no order between case name?
Like blow

```
+-----+------+------------+
| SN  | CASE | CASE_VALUE |
+-----+------+------------+
|  A  |  AB  |      1     |
|  A  |  CD  |      5     |
|  A  |  IJ  |      3     |
|  A  |  GH  |      4     |
|  B  |  OP  |      5     |
|  B  |  EF  |      7     |
|  B  |  MN  |      5     |
|  B  |  KJ  |      1     |
+-----+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is using conditional aggregation in order to pivot as desired such as

```
SELECT sn,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'A' THEN case END) AS case_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'A' THEN case_value END) AS case_1_value,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'B' THEN case END) AS case_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'B' THEN case_value END) AS case_2_value,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'C' THEN case END) AS case_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'C' THEN case_value END) AS case_3_value,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'D' THEN case END) AS case_4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = 'D' THEN case_value END) AS case_4_value                     
  FROM t
 GROUP BY sn
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d2a043e1a511561260155d76bec7521)</kbd>

The pivot is static in the above case. You can create a function returning of `SYS_REFCURSOR` type as below one in order to have a dynamic pivot

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Cols RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);   
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = '''||cs||''' THEN case END )  AS  "case_'||rn||'",
                   MAX(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(case,2,1) = '''||cs||''' THEN case_value END )  AS  "case_'||rn||'_value"', ',')
           WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY rn )                     
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(case,2,1) AS cs, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY case) AS rn
             FROM t );
   
  v_sql :='SELECT sn,'|| v_cols ||' FROM t GROUP BY sn';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and call from *SQL Developer*'s Command Line in order to see the result set

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Pivoted_Cols;
PRINT rc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot rows, then to use decode function to map your output like below. (I hope CASE is not the real name of your column).

```sql
with your_data (SN, "CASE", CASE_VALUE ) as (
select 'A', 'AA', 1 from dual union all
select 'A', 'AB', 5 from dual union all
select 'A', 'AC', 3 from dual union all
select 'A', 'AD', 4 from dual union all
select 'B', 'BA', 5 from dual union all
select 'B', 'BB', 7 from dual union all
select 'B', 'BC', 5 from dual union all
select 'B', 'BD', 1 from dual
)
select SN
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_1, CASE_5)CASE_1
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_1_VALUE, CASE_5_VALUE)CASE_1_VALUE
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_2, CASE_6)CASE_2
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_2_VALUE, CASE_6_VALUE)CASE_2_VALUE
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_3, CASE_7)CASE_3
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_3_VALUE, CASE_7_VALUE)CASE_3_VALUE
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_4, CASE_8)CASE_4
, decode(SN, 'A', CASE_4_VALUE, CASE_8_VALUE)CASE_4_VALUE
from your_data t
pivot (
max(case_value) as value, max("CASE") FOR "CASE" in (
 'AA' CASE_1
,'AB' CASE_2
,'AC' CASE_3
,'AD' CASE_4
,'BA' CASE_5
,'BB' CASE_6
,'BC' CASE_7
,'BD' CASE_8
  )
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest I could get, assuming (based on your data) that the first character in `case` will always match with `sn` we can pivot on that second character

```
select *
from (
  select
    data.*
  , substr(case, 2, 1) case_t
  from data
)
pivot (
  max(case) type
, max(case_value) value

  for case_t in (
    'A' case_1
  , 'B' case_2
  , 'C' case_3
  , 'D' case_4
  )
)
```